# Cannot find libcrypto in Ubuntu

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu

I want to try one program which have makefile on it but when I put `make` in the shell the error  was:

```
 g++ -g -DaUNIX -I../../acroname/aInclude -I../../acroname/aSource -Wl,-rpath,.     unix_aLaserDemo_Data/aLaserDemo.o unix_aLaserDemo_Data/acpLaser.o -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl  -o ../../acroname/aBinary/aLaserDemo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the makefile:

```
 CC = g++
 CFLAGS = -DaUNIX -I../../acroname/aInclude -I../../acroname/aSource
 LFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath,.
 SRC = ../../acroname/aSource
 BIN = ../../acroname/aBinary
 LIBS = -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl \
 #LIBS = -lpthread\
       -L../../acroname/aBinary -l aUtil -l aIO
 OBJ = unix_aLaserDemo_Data

.PHONY : app
 app : $(OBJ) $(BIN)/aLaserDemo

$(OBJ) :
        mkdir $(OBJ)

$(BIN)/aLaserDemo : $(OBJ)/aLaserDemo.o $(OBJ)/acpLaser.o
        $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

$(OBJ)/aLaserDemo.o : aLaserDemo.cpp
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OBJ)/acpLaser.o : $(SRC)/acpLaser.cpp $(SRC)/acpLaser.h
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

 .PHONY : clean
 clean :
    rm -rf $(OBJ)
    rm -f $(BIN)/aLaserDemo
```

I try to locate the crypto library:

```
 /usr/lib/i486/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
 /usr/lib/i586/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
 /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: how we know it is 64 bits or 32 bit? I am beginner in linux.

Comment: You need to install the development code (package) for the crypto library.  Specifically, you need `/usr/lib/libcrypto.so` (no numerical suffix) pointing at (symlinked to) `/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8`.  The linking process looks for a name ending `.so`; the run-time looks for the name with the versioned suffix.  The `devel` package will ensure the right links are created for development with the crypto library; what you have at the moment is only for the runtime.

Comment: you can do `uname -a` to check if it is 64bit. Also do `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` to install development package.

Comment: unfortunatly I have not a root access. I try to #LIBS = -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl \ and change to LIBS = -lpthread\ but there are much more errors occur

Comment: When I do uname -a the result is :      Linux pc4268 2.6.20-16-generic #2 SMP Sun Sep 23 19:50:39 UTC 2007 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Try adding `-L/usr/lib/i686/cmov` to `LFLAGS`. While the compiler (linker) should automatically pick up `/usr/lib/libcrypto`, the latter's probably a symbolic link to one of the others. See if pointing to such an explicit directory works.

Comment: Thank you Evert I add and here the result.  /usr/bin/ld: .: No such file: File format not recognized

Answer (score 153, accepted):

I solved this on 12.10 by installing libssl-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: I got a `configure: error: *** working libcrypto not found, check config.log` when running the configure script of OpenSSH and your answer fixed my issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

`ld` is trying to find `libcrypto.so`which is not present as seen in your `locate` output.
 You can make a copy of the `libcrypto.so.0.9.8` and name it as `libcrypto.so`. Put this is your ld path. ( If you do not have root access then you can put it in a local path and specify the path manually )

Comment: Can you specify how to put `libcrypto.so` in ld path ?