# libcrypto.so.0.9.7: cannot open shared object file

Tags: shared-libraries, fedora, libcrypto

I have searched the net for this question and I'm not getting a proper response. 
I am running an in-house application which requires libcrypto.so.0.9.7.

But I keep getting the following error:

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.0.9.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I came across two solutions on the net:

1. Creating symlinks with existing libcrypto files.
2. Install some package which includes this library file.

I am running it on a fedora system. I am not able to find packages on the net that include this library. The only ones available are for OpenSuse and Mandriva.

For creating symlinks, I have a libcrypto.so.1.0.0h and libcrypto.so.1.0.0d file available. I am not sure if I am allowed to symlink to a newer version.

It would be of great help if someone can give an apt solution for this scenario as I have faced it many times in different systems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find libcrypto in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811889/cannot-find-libcrypto-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes get away with creating symlinks if the libraries are binary compatible but in your case you're going between 0.X and 1.X versions so I'm guessing they wouldn't be. Even if it does run it might not work properly.

You can try to find a package using sites like rpmfind.net, but usually you're not going to find older versions.

I think a third option is to rebuild libcrypto from source. Depending on how you build and install it you may have to add a new directory to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to get it to find your newly compiled shared objects. You can download source from openssl.org.

Please note that if possible I'd strongly suggest finding a way to rebuild your application against the latest version of OpenSSL to make sure you're not vulnerable to the recent heartbleed security problems (see [heartbleed.com](http://www.heartbleed.com)).