# How to fix : -- snmpget: "error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

snmpget: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: It means `snmpget` depends on the `libcrypto` to be installed on your system. Not sure how you managed to install it without the library. Your distribution likely provide proper packages for both with dependencies handled properly.

Comment: root@Quy:~# snmpget -v2 -c public 127.0.0.1 sysDescr.0
snmpget: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

root@Quy:~# snmpwalk -v2 -c public 127.0.0.1 sysDescr.0
snmpwalk: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find libcrypto in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811889/cannot-find-libcrypto-in-ubuntu)

Comment: im try to fix, but not ok

Comment: What should I do to fix it?